# what's wrong with golang constant overflows uint64

Tags: go, integer-overflow

```
userid := 12345
did := (userid & ^(0xFFFF << 48))
```

when compiling this code, I got:

> `./xxxx.go:511: constant -18446462598732840961 overflows int`

Do you know what is the matter with this and how to solve it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^(0xFFFF << 48)` is an untyped constant, which in go is an arbitrarily large value.

`0xffff << 48` is `0xffff000000000000`. When you negate it, you get `-0xffff000000000001` (since with two's complement, -x = ^x + 1, or ^x = -(x + 1)).

When you write `userid := 12345`, `userid` gets the type `int`. Then when you try to and (`&`) it with the untyped constant `-0xffff000000000001` the compiler figures that this constant needs to be an `int`. At this point, the compiler complains because the value is too large in magnitude to be an `int`.

If you're trying to get the constant `0x0000ffffffffffff`, then you can use `1<<48 - 1`, which (if you've got 64-bit ints), will fit. Since your code will never work if `int` is 32-bits, then you should probably use `int64` in your code rather than `int` to make it portable.

The blog post https://blog.golang.org/constants explains how constants work, and some background on why they are the way they are.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not
>   overflow.
>
> Constants may be typed or untyped.
>
> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or
>   conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an
>   assignment or as an operand in an expression. It is an error if the
>   constant value cannot be represented as a value of the respective
>   type.
>
> An untyped constant has a default type which is the type to which the
>   constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is
>   required, for instance, in a short variable declaration such as i := 0
>   where there is no explicit type. The default type of an untyped
>   constant is bool, rune, int, float64, complex128 or string
>   respectively, depending on whether it is a boolean, rune, integer,
>   floating-point, complex, or string constant.
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> `int` is an implementation-specific size, either 32 or 64 bits.

`userid` is of type `int`. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    userid := 12345
    did := uint64(userid) & ^uint64(0xFFFF<<48)
    fmt.Println(userid, did)
}
```

Output:

```
12345 12345
```