# No panic when converting int to uint?

Tags: go

I'm confused about the following type conversion. I would expect both `uint` conversions to panic.

```
a := -1
_ = uint(a) // why no panic?

_ = uint(-1) // panics: constant -1 overflows uint
```

Why doesn't it panic in line 2?

https://play.golang.org/p/jcfDL8km2C

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Comment: Mostly because it knows the literal's value, so it can tell you right away that it is a silly idea. And it doesn't do it at runtime because the runtime cost is too high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [issue 6923](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6923):

> `T(c)` where `T` is a type and `c` is a constant means to treat `c` as having type `T` rather than one of the default types.
> It gives an error if `c` can not be represented in `T`, except that for `float` and `complex` constants we quietly round to `T` as long as the value is not too large.

Here:

```
const x uint = -1
var x uint = -1
```

> This doesn't work because -1 cannot be (implicitly) **[converted](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)** to a uint.

```
_ = uint(a) // why no panic?
```

Because `a` is not an untyped constant, but a typed variable (`int`). See [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FV3ln7rwiO) and "[what's wrong with Golang constant overflows uint64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787847/6309)":

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := -1
    _ = uint(a) // why no panic?
    var b uint
    b = uint(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
    // _ = uint(-1) // panics: main.go:7: constant -1 overflows uint
}
```

Result: `4294967295` (on 32-bits system) or `18446744073709551615` (on 64-bits system), as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918232/no-panic-when-converting-int-to-uint#comment126436098_41918281) by [starriet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10027592/starriet)

That are specific rules for the conversion of non-constant numeric values:

> When converting between integer types, if the value is a signed integer, it is sign extended to implicit infinite precision; otherwise it is zero extended.
> It is then truncated to fit in the result type's size.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/2L7NfqtZYls

Comment: @mattes, see also [a must-read post on Go constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants) which, among other things, deals with defining constant for maximum integer values of various types.

Comment: For ppl like me: Now if you run the code above, you'll get `18446744073709551615`(decimal) if you use a 64bit system. And if you convert this to a binary, you'll get `11111111111......`(64 ones). The decimal `4294967295` in the original answer is `1111....`(32 ones) in binary. It's because the size of `int` or `uint` depends on the system(32bit or 64bit).

Comment: @starriet Good point. I have edited the answer to reflect the system int size.